# Ethernet with different color codes?

Tags: networking, ethernet

In  my Ethernet RJ-45 cable, I don't see any brown or green wires. There are only white, orange and blue wires. But the color codes for TIA/EIA568 wiring according to the CCNA and on the internet has orange, blue, green and brown. Are there different color codes now?

Comment: What colors do you see?

Comment: Are there 8 wires?

Comment: @Zoredache : white, orange and blue.

Comment: @Josh : can't make out there are too many white colored wires side by side. hard to differentiate. but as far as I can see yes. Am just guessing by the width of a orange wire which is between these white wires.

Comment: well, the pairs are/should be twisted together.  So, if you can identify a couple colors, then you at least know that orange is twisted with orange/white, blue with blue/white, etc.  If the others really are totally blank(white), your best bet will probably be build a cable and test it with a cable tester.  That will at least tell you which pairs are out of order.  Pain in the butt for sure, but hey, odds are you'll get some of them right the first time :)

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manufacturers don't *have* to color them according to standards.

I once ran in to an awful roll of cable donated to my school that didn't have striped colors on the pairs, just one solid color cable and one white cable. After losing track of which white cable went with which color a dozen times we realized why they had donated that half-used abomination.

Comment: This is it, sadly.